# AngularJS Form - Default Value for Select

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to create an angularjs form with two fields, one text input and a select. By default, the text input is blank but the select should have a value (the first element on the select). I'm following the angularjs form docs and using a master object which on reset is copied into the page's model. Here's the thing, if I set the select to something by default it comes blank. If I do the same with the text field it displays the default value. Below you'll find my code and here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KO8X85RWNCVfDxugR3Qe?p=preview). I think it might have to do with the copy being made on the reset function but I'm printing the object to the console at that point and it looks like it's being copied. If I try to do this without the master stuff, just setting it straight to the user and not calling reset it works ok.

**controller**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.businessUnits = [{"businessUnitId":1,"name":"Auto"},{"businessUnitId":2,"name":"Life"},{"businessUnitId":3,"name":"Health"},{"businessUnitId":4,"name":"Surety"},{"businessUnitId":5,"name":"Finance"},{"businessUnitId":6,"name":"Dwelling"}];
    $scope.master.businessUnit = $scope.businessUnits[0];
    $scope.master.name = "John";

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
      if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
      }
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
      console.debug($scope.user.businessUnit);
    };
    $scope.reset();
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example33-production</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uName.$touched">
      <div ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
    </div>

    E-mail:
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
      <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
    </div>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user.businessUnit" ng-options="unit as unit.name for unit in businessUnits" required></select>
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.agree" name="userAgree" required="" />

    I agree:
    <input ng-show="user.agree" type="text" ng-model="user.agreeSign" required="" />
    <br />
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.userAgree.$touched">
      <div ng-show="!user.agree || !user.agreeSign">Please agree and sign.</div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" ng-click="reset(form)" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your `<select>`

```
ng-init="user.businessUnit = businessUnits[0]"
```

It should look like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="user.businessUnit" ng-init="user.businessUnit = businessUnits[0]" ng-options="unit as unit.name for unit in businessUnits" required></select>
```

Comment: That did it. Any idea why it wouldn't set it through the controller's reset function?